# How to define the function

Tags: variable-definitions

How to define this function?
    $$
 A_{n,k}:=
 \begin{cases}
 0, & \mathrm{if } \ k<0 \\
 1, & \mathrm{if } \ k=0 \\
 (2k+1)\binom{2k}{k} \sum_{n\geq j\geq 2k+1} A_{j,n} \binom{j}{2k+1}        
 \frac{(-1)^{j-1}}{j-k} B_{2j-2k}, & \mathrm{if } \ 0 < k < n \\
 (2k+1)\binom{2k}{k}, & \mathrm{if } \ k=n \\
 0, & \mathrm{if } \ k > n
 \end{cases}
$$
We have already a woking code, but it doesnt gives $A_{n,0}\neq1$ this question abut fixing of initial code at the [link](https://kolosovpetro.github.io/mathematica_codes/Math_code_new.txt)

Comment: Have a look for `Piecewise`.

Comment: this is almost duplicate :) thanks for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this fix:

```
ClearAll[T]
T[n_, k_] := 0 /; k < 0;
T[n_, 0] := 1;
T[n_, k_] := (2 k + 1)*Binomial[2 k, k]*
    Sum[T[j, n]*Binomial[j, 2 k + 1]*(-1)^(j - 1)/(j - k)*
      BernoulliB[2 j - 2 k], {j, 2 k + 1, n}] /; 2 k + 1 <= n;
T[n_, k_] := (2 n + 1)*Binomial[2 n, n] /; k == n;

T[3, 0]    
(* 1 *)
```

I replaced the first line of [your definition](https://kolosovpetro.github.io/mathematica_codes/Math_code_new.txt), `T[n_, k_] := 0`, with

```
T[n_, k_] := 0 /; k < 0;
T[n_, 0] := 1;
```

Comment: Doesn't work properly, suppose to give the terms of the table https://kolosovpetro.github.io/pdf/coefficients_of_polynomial.pdf ; previous version of the code gives everything properly, except T[n,0]

Comment: @KolosovPetro  Please observe that my fix adheres to the definition of the piecewise function in your question.